# Searching in an Excel Worksheet a list of keywords from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to search a list of keywords from an Excel sheet in another sheet using VBA and highlight them when found.
Do you have any idea how to complete this task?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the list of keywords is in a range, and the cells to be highlighted contain nothing but the keyword, rather than the keyword in among some other text;

```
Dim Keywords as Range
set keywords = Sht1.Range("A1:B2") 'Enter your relevant keyword range

Dim cell as Range
For each Cell in Sht2.UsedRange 'Or choose a smaller range to speed it up.
    If WorksheetFunction.Countif(Keywords, Cell.value)>0 then
        Cell.Interior.Colour = vbYellow
        'Or whatever else you'd do to that cell
    End If
Next
```

Comment: As per @TomaszPaluch's comment, SO isn't really for code writing but I use this snippet myself a bit so copied it out for you. Hope it works.

Comment: Yes, the list of keywords is in a range but the cells to be highlighted contain more text.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: ah, sorry about that. You'll need a nested loop then, to check for each keyword individually; `If cell.value like "*" & Keyword & "*" Then...`